# How to make the service to be accessible for components inside @Input template

Tags: angular

Suppose I have a host component, it has a `MyService` in providers and an input `template`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-host',
  templateUrl: './host.component.html',
  providers: [MyService],
})
export class HostComponent {
  @Input()
  template: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

```html
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"> </ng-container>
```

I also have an `item` component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-element',
  templateUrl: './item-element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-element.component.css'],
})
export class ItemElementComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Optional() private my: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('My Service', this.my);
  }
}
```

And I use both of them the following way (it doesn't matter where):

```html
<app-host [template]="item"></app-host>

<ng-template #item>
  <app-item-element></app-item-element>
</ng-template>
```

Despite the fact that an item component is a child of the app-host component, it doesn't get the service instance - `@Optional` injection provides `null`. I understand why it happens. But still, is there a way to make this service to be accessible for component inside of template? And there is a reason I don't want to relocate the service provider from the app-host level up to a parent level where I link template & app-host.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oa54sa)

Comment: You can not pass injector to template, but can to component (https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef). Though that hardly helps(

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the service into the template as an `@Input`  via `ngTemplateOutletContext` - not an ideal solution, but might be an option

Comment: Not in my case :-( In the original project, there is a directive which can be used or not, and I don't know how it will be used, and how many levels between this host component & these directives. This directive performs some logic, but I has to perform an additional logic if it used inside specific host component.